# Is it okay to ask opinion based questions in meta?

Tags: support

I have some opinion based questions that I'd love to ask the community; however, I understand that those kinds of questions are not allowed normally. Is it okay if I ask them here, in meta, or is there a better place?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room) is a better place for opinion based questions. Meta is more for questions about the site itself (like you've done here!).

Comment: Just to amplify this: I wish more people would use chat generally and for opinion-based questions specifically. I, for one, would certainly participate in any discussion where I had something relevant to contribute.

Comment: @Aaron There's something I find intimidating at the idea of using the chat, I don't know why (even though I went there twice up until now).